# How to do SAML 2.0 Auth from Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, saml-2.0

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that will have to authenticate against SAML 2.0, I have researched and all plugins and libraries are either too old or do not support SAML 2.0. Any idea or suggestion on how it could be done for Xamarin.Forms?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAML2 is a web single sign on protocol and is not meant to be used by a mobile application.

For a mobile application you want both authentication at the mobile app level, as well as a bearer token for calls to backend APIS. OpenID Connect is the solution for that. So you should set up your application to use OpenID Connect and then use a token issuer that can authenticate users through SAML2. IdentityServer4 together with Saml2 authentication handler is a good open source option for that.